# Overlay SVG background with SVG icons on fixed positions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to create a ReactJS website for displaying a floor plan with icons overlaying it.  The icons will be set dynamically depending on status of sensor values.  I'm using react-zoom-pan-pinch to zoom and pan/pinch the floor plan on desktop and mobile devices.

But I have been unable to find a way to display the icons overlaying the background in such a way that the icons remain in place when the browser is resized.

I've created a CodeSandbox to illustrate my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chaplygin-k0ded

Any ideas?

Comment: instead of using percentage values, use a fixed amount of pixels to displace the icons left and right, and calculate that fixed value and set it when the page is resized, this should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-frost-0zz1z

Use fixed position in terms of pixels but change the amount according to the window inner bounds, i've added in more details in the sandbox.

Comment: The icons are still not in fixed positions overlaying the background.  Try resizing the browser window.

Comment: if you want them to be fixed over a specific position, you have to calculate where to place the icons on the background yourself, and position the icons over those points using those co-ordinates, if you want to achieve that

Comment: I think I may have described my problem poorly, when looking at what you propose.  I'm not looking for a solution on how to place an icon in every corner and one icon in the center.  That was just an example.  I want to add one or more icons with a defined horizontal and vertical position, and for the icon(s) to remain in a fixed position in relation to the background.  Same goes for size of the icon.  The background is scaled when resizing the window, but the icons are not.  And I'm unable to find a solution that covers it all.